# Upgraded 16.04 to 18.04, won't let me log in

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, login

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04. After rebooting, I get my normal login screen, which still says "Ubuntu 16.04". I click my name and enter my password, and so far get one of the three following:

1. The login box vanishes, but the screen remains the same (with my desktop background and the Ubuntu 16.04 text and nothing else). This stays for minutes with nothing happening.
2. I get the login prompt back.
3. I get a black screen.

What would be my next step? Will I need to make a clean install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question in jolindbe's own words copied from a comment which was posted an hour ago is:

> As for my problem (above), I finally managed to login to the Ubuntu prompt, and from there I could find that some packages were not correctly updated. After updating those, I ended up with a (mostly) perfectly working 18.04 system.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I just now foolishly allowed Ubuntu to install a backlog of updates and when I rebooted I suddenly found myself in this login loop. Clearly Ubuntu no longer recognizes who I am.

So when booting up, after the BIOS screen goes away I press down on the SHIFT key. I then get a GRUB screen that allows me to choose "Advanced Options for Ubuntu". Selecting that, I choose to boot up using an older generic, non-recovery mode kernel version. I am then able to login with my account normally.  This will hold me over until I have the time to dig deeper into this puzzling problem.

Comment: Since this is not a solution to the question, please consider posting it as a comment rather than an answer. As for my problem (above), I finally managed to log in to the Ubuntu prompt, and from there I could find that some packages were not correctly updated. After updating those, I ended up with a (mostly) perfectly working 18.04 system.